# Query database rows where timestamp column is older than X hours

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, date

I have a bunch of rows in a MySQL database table, with a *last_update* (TIMESTAMP) field to log when they were last modified. As of right now, I loop through all of the rows every 300 seconds and check to see if 3+ hours have elapsed, and then update that row if so.

```
    $update_delay = 180;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "products";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, prod_id, last_update FROM $table_name" );

    foreach ($results as $result)
    {
        $last_update = $result->last_update;

        if (time() - strtotime($last_update) > $update_delay * 60)
        {
```

As this is inefficient, I would like to query just the rows where the timestamp is older than 3 hours. Since that field has the format of "2020-03-01 23:22:06" I think I can do something like the following, but am not sure if I can do this using INTERVAL in the query, or if the date to check against should be in PHP.

```
$old_timestamp = date('Y-m-d G:i:s') . "- 3 hours";

$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, prod_id FROM $table_name WHERE last_update > $old_timestamp" );
```

What would be a good option to implement this efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to query just the rows where the timestamp is older than 3 hours

No need for specific application code. MySQL understands date arithmetics:

```
WHERE last_update > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR
```

Comment: It looks like it should have been less than rather than greater than (which is what I had put in my original post) but otherwise this is perfect. Thanks so much, code is a lot better now!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$old_timestamp = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 
    "SELECT id, prod_id FROM $table_name WHERE last_update > date_add($old_timestamp") -3 hours)
);
```